# Leaflet map not rendering full image properly on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working in a react web-app. We are using leaflet to render some buildings maps. The app is working good in desktop. But we found the maps images are not loaded properly when using mobile navigator.
The map started loading but seems cropped, until you switch to other app and return to the app/page again you can see the full image. In some pages the image seems cropped but when scroll or zoom-in, zoom-out the image loads well.

[image: Image not loadingImage loading after switch back to the page]

[image: full image loading after switch back]
I have tried to use invalidateSize() function but seems not working.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mapAttributes = {
      attributionControl: false,
      minZoom: -4,
      zoomDelta: 0.25,
      zoomSnap: 0.25,
      wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 150,
      crs: L.CRS[coordinateSystem],
      zoomControl: isShowZoomControl,
    };

    const map = L.map(mapRef.current, {
      ...mapAttributes,
    });

    L.imageOverlay(backgroundImageUrl, mapBounds).addTo(map);

    const defaultMarkerPaneZIndex = 600;
    map.createPane(mapPanes.markerNotifications);
    map.getPane(mapPanes.markerNotifications).style.zIndex = defaultMarkerPaneZIndex + 1;

    setMapObj(map);

    return () => {
      setMapObj(null);
      map.off();
      map.remove();
    };
  }, [
    backgroundImageUrl,
    buildingUuid,
    controlBoundariesCallback,
    coordinateSystem,
    floorUuid,
    isShowZoomControl,
    mapBounds,
  ]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapObj) return;

    mapObj.invalidateSize();
  }, [mapObj);
```